# Arch Linux - installation with old iso image

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

Are there any issues when installing Arch Linux with an old ISO image? Generally all packages are downloaded from mirrors during installation, but I want to be sure.

Comment: How old is the iso image?

Comment: If the image is last-year, you can install all. You'd only need to manually correct some problems and make a downgrade to uninstall systemd.

Comment: This is only my assumptions, but images are never older than 1-3 months.

Comment: Any reason not to try it and see?

Comment: @Eddy_Em Uninstalling systemd is not a helpful, or realistic, suggestion: `initscripts` are no longer supported...

Comment: @Kevin: I was just wondering, because I install Arch several times a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how old the image is. You should read the [News on the Arch Linux home page](https://www.archlinux.org/news/) to see what has changed since the image you are proposing to use. For example, anything older than October 2012 [is pre-systemd](https://www.archlinux.org/news/install-medium-20121006-introduces-systemd/).

Having said that, Arch is a rolling release and if you cannot readily obtain up-to-date installation media, then you will probably struggle maintaining it. If at all possible, [download the current image](https://www.archlinux.org/download/) and install from that.

Comment: Agreed.  The change to systemd seemed pretty drastic.  Get the most up-to-date ISO you can, just to avoid having to do the complicated switch to systemd.